# Generic type parameter for a method

Tags: c#, generics

How do I create a method that accepts generic parameters?

Ok, here's the exact thing I'm working on:

The 2 methods below differ only by `By.Id` or `By.LinkText`

```
    private IWebElement FindElementById(string id)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
        IWebElement we = null;

        wait.Until<bool>(x =>
        {
            we = x.FindElement(By.Id(id));
            bool isFound = false;

            try
            {
                if (we != null)
                    isFound = true;
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
                we = x.FindElement(By.Id(id));
            }

            return isFound;
        });

        return we;
    }

    private IWebElement FindElementByLinkText(string id)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
        IWebElement we = null;

        wait.Until<bool>(x =>
        {
            we = x.FindElement(By.LinkText(id));
            bool isFound = false;

            try
            {
                if (we != null)
                    isFound = true;
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
                we = x.FindElement(By.LinkText(id));
            }

            return isFound;
        });

        return we;
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question more? I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Generics allow you to specify the *type* of the data being returned or passed to the method at run time. It doesn't look like thats the case here, all you need is a method that takes an `enum` and a string...

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look into [Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) - `Expression<Func<String>>`?

Comment: You're looking for `public Customer Get<T>(Expression<Func<Customer, T>> expr, T value)`. The implementation of that method depends on where you're getting the data from and what APIs are you using there.

Comment: How is anyone suppose to understand this question, you went from this signature `public Customer Get(generics here, value)` to `IWebElement FindElementByLinkText(string id)`.  I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I apologize, I was trying to simplify it and ended making it worse

Comment: @Rod And, if you just don't want to repeat yourself in these methods, then why don't you create one method that accepts single `By` instance and call such method from two more specific methods(String)? Because it doesn't seem that expressions will allow you to create simple solution to use with Selenium(?) API - some reflection and lookup will probably still be required.

Comment: @Rod, did you have a look at my answer? Does it address your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the Selenium `By` functions are static member functions conforming to the type signature of a `Func<string, By>`, you could easily modify your code like this:

```
private IWebElement FindElementById(string id)
{
    return FindElementBy(By.Id, id);
}

private IWebElement FindElementByLinkText(string linkText)
{
    return FindElementBy(By.LinkText, linkText);
}

private IWebElement FindElementBy(Func<string, By> finder, string argument)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
    IWebElement we = null;

    wait.Until<bool>(x =>
    {
        we = x.FindElement(finder(argument));
        bool isFound = false;

        try
        {
            if (we != null)
                isFound = true;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            we = x.FindElement(finder(argument));
        }

        return isFound;
    });

    return we;
}
```